# Archlinux + GSSapi + kerberos

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, openssh, kerberos

I am trying to use ssh supporting `GSSAPI with KeyExchange` protocol with some servers that authenticate using kerberos. I have installed `aur/openssh-gssapi`. The problems is after getting the key from krb-server using `kinit`, when I ssh to the server it fails with this message:

```
Unable to negotiate with blah.blah: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==
```

It says that they offer: [the key exchange above], but I have its support in my offerings:

```
debug1: Offering GSSAPI proposal: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group1-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group14-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-gex-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group1-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group14-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-gex-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group1-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group14-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==
```

I wonder what could be the cause of this problem!?

Edit: since I didn't see the point I did not post the log output of ssh command but just in case I am going to paste it in here:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: null
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
Unable to negotiate with yada.yada: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==
```

Comment: Post the whole log and ideally the link to the gssapi patch that is applied in your package. It might be modified wrongly.

Comment: Well I think whoever uses archlinux knows how and what patches are applied to the openssh-server that I pointed at. The spec file is this: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=openssh-gssapi

Comment: No, your client does not support any of GSSAPI kex algorithms: `debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the [patch in Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/gssapi-p0.patch?h=openssh-gssapi). They are setting the Kexs, but they are immediately overwritten by the other changes in the code:

The line

```
xasprintf(&myproposal[PROPOSAL_KEX_ALGS], "%s,%s", gss, orig);
```

should say

```
xasprintf(&options.kex_algorithms, "%s,%s", gss, orig);
```

From the brief check of the [source against what we ship in Fedora](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/openssh.git/tree/openssh-7.2p1-gsskex.patch).

Edit: Of course also this line:

```
orig = myproposal[PROPOSAL_KEX_ALGS];
```

should be

```
orig = options.kex_algorithms;
```

Comment: Feel free to test and report the to the Arch maintainers. I am not familiar with their processes.

Comment: I am waiting for my account to be approved on their forum. I will report it as fast as it gets through. thanks. I will test it right away.

Comment: Not only I am very thankful but I am also very impressed how fast you found the problem.

Comment: Well ... this was one of more tricky parts during recent rebases of the same patch in Fedora so I quite remember what could go wrong if the author does not pay enough attention to the context :)